# Database for efficient search on time series data combined with simple data?

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, time-series

Let's say we have ads and their stats. Ads presented as title, text, status and other fields. For example:

```
{
  "id":1,
  "title":"Buy a car",
  "text":"Buy a car today",
  "status":"ON"
}
```

Stats presented as time series data. For example:

```
[
  {
    "adId":1,
    "date":"2018-01-01",
    "clicks":200
  },
  {
    "adId":1,
    "date":"2018-01-02",
    "clicks":250
  }
]
```

Data can change in both stats and ads so we can not save ad data with each stat.

What we want:

- make queries like this: select all ads which are enabled, have 'car' in their text and have more then 1000 clicks in January. Queries are dynamic and issued from UI.
- sorting on all fields(including sorting by clicks)
- pagination

Our current choice is Elasticsearch and mapping like this:

```
{
  "id":1,
  "title":"Buy a car",
  "text":"Buy a car today",
  "status":"ON",
  "stats":
    [
      {
        "adId":1,
        "date":"2018-01-01",
        "clicks":200
      },
      {
        "adId":1,
        "date":"2018-01-02",
        "clicks":250
      }
    ]
}
```

It almost works, but queries are very complicated with crazy aggregations and tricky pagination. And haven't started sorting yet.
I'm also looking at Cassandra, but it seems to me that there is no simple solution and either you have simple solution for time series or simple solution for ordinary data, but not both.
What db to choose and how to model data inside of it?

Comment: Ever looked at a timeseriesdb? KairosDB? OpenTSDB?

Comment: @Mandraenke didn't go deep into them. Do they solve such problem?